# HTML for loop inside ul element

Tags: python, html, django-templates

Say I want to print out the numbers 0 to 4 on an HTML page. How would I change the following code to do it:

```
<ul>
   {%for i in range(5) %}
       <li><a>i</a></li>
   {%endfor %}         
</ul>
```

Comment: first you'd have to explain what templating system you'd use. but note that your `i` is just a plaintext `i`. If you want it to be treated as your loop variable, you'll have to mark it as a variable - otherwise the `i` in `<li>` would also become `<l1>`, `<l2>` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a serverside language, say, PHP:

```
<ul>
  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++): ?>
    <li><a><?=$i?></a></li>
  <?php endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

Or, Django:

```
<ul>
  {% for i in 5|get_range %}
    <li>{{ i }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Otherwise, you'll need to do it after the page loaded, with javascript, here's a [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/qbapa3ru/).

```
<ul id="dynamicList"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
     var list = document.getElementById('dynamicList');
     for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       var li = document.createElement('li');
       li.innerHTML = i;
       list.appendChild(li);
     }
  })();
</script>
```